# Spring AMQP with two ConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I have an application with two ConnectionFactory (different brokers). They are configured with java classes:

```
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory ...

    @Bean
    public Queue ...
...
```

In rabbittemplate you can indicate the connection, but not in queues or in the exchanges, so they are being created in the two connections. 
Do I have to use RabbitAdmin to create queues in only one of the two connections? is there any other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [the documentation : Conditional Declaration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#conditional-declaration).

> Starting with the 1.2 release, it is possible to conditionally declare these elements. This is particularly useful when an application connects to multiple brokers and needs to specify with which broker(s) a particular element should be declared.

You need a `RabbitAdmin` for each connection factory and use `declared-by` to indicate which admin(s) should declare each queue/exchange/binding.

Comment: Question: how do you configure these 2 connection factories with their own RabbitAdmin? I have a SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory in which I can only do `factory.setConnectionFactory(amqpConnectionFactory());`. How do I configure the second one?

Comment: The `RabbitAdmin` is a different bean to the connection factory bean. Simply define multiple beans of each type, giving them unique names.